# Authenticating a user with j_security_check in Java EE 7

Tags: servlets, tomcat7, forms-authentication, java-ee-7, j-security-check

I practise **Java EE 7** nowadays. I come across a problem when trying to authenticate a user by using container provided way, i.e., `j_security_check` .

- Application server: `Apache Tomcat 7`
- Project/Application name: `ServletDrill`
- Resource (Servlet) annotated with `@WebServlet`

My `Web.xml`:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>ServletDrill</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>To_Auth</web-resource-name>      
      <url-pattern>/auth/*</url-pattern>
      <http-method>GET</http-method>
      <http-method>POST</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
      <role-name>valid</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
  </security-constraint>

  <login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>    
    <form-login-config>
      <form-login-page>/FormAuth.jsp</form-login-page>
      <form-error-page>/LogInErr.jsp</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
  </login-config>
</web-app>
```

My `tomcat-users.xml`:

```
<tomcat-users>
<role rolename="valid"/> 
 <user username="username" password="pass" roles="valid"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

My `<form>`:

```
<form action="/ServletDrill/j_security_check" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
<fieldset id="postForm">
<legend>j_security_check method</legend>
<div class="partContainer">
<div class="left"><label for="user" >User Name: </label></div>
<div class="right"><input type="text" name="j_username" id="user" required="required" maxlength="20"></div>
</div>
<hr/>

<div class="partContainer">
<div class="left"><label for="pass" >Pass: </label></div>
<div class="right"><input type="password" name="j_password" id="pass" required="required" maxlength="20"></div>
</div>

<hr/>
<div class="partContainer">
<div class="left"><input type="submit" value="Log In"></div>
<div class="right"><input type="reset" value="Reset"></div>
</div>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

My protected resource (Servlet):

```
@WebServlet("/auth/NeedsPriorAuth")
public final class NeedsPriorAuth extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {       
        response.getWriter().append("Welcome, "+request.getRemoteUser()+". The user has been authenticated before hand").append("\n Auth Type: "+request.getAuthType());
    }
}
```

When I execute the following link,

```
 <a href="/ServletDrill/auth/NeedsPriorAuth">Access Protected Servlet</a>
```

,the user redirected for authentication on the following page,

```
<form-login-page>/FormAuth.jsp</form-login-page>
```

(the `<form>` that I posted above).
Despite passing in correct credentials (posted above at `tomcat-users.xml`) the user redirected to the following Error page (posted above at `Web.xml`):

```
<form-error-page>/LogInErr.jsp</form-error-page>
```

What is the culprit which causes such an inconvenience for me? I've been stuck on this problem for several days now. 
What about `<realm>`, do I need it?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There you go, in the end, I have resolved the problem. The modification that I needed to apply:

```
<form action="j_security_check" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
```

That is, the **action** has no application context prefix.
The other thing, is that there are, in my case, 2 instances of **tomcat-users.xml** file:

- Under Apache Tomcat v7 directory (The server app)
- And the one accessible from `Project Explorer in Eclipse`, under **Servers2** name

When you modify the role(s), username, and password, if you want to see an affect to take place, modify it under the latter instance example; the server restart comes after.